# Coo muestro numeros en un select desde Java Script

Tags: javascript, select, card

Estoy haciendo un card validation y quiero poner en un select los meses del año (en numeros) y en otro select al menos 10 años (en numeros) pero quiero que esta asignacion sea desde Java Script. Había pensado en usar un for pero no tengo claro como hacer que se asigne los datos al select desde el script.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En JavaScript puedes usar la funcion createElement para definir un nuevo objeto y la funcion appendChild para agregar este elemento a otro predefinido

Ejemplo:

```js
     //Define la lista a modificar
      let list = document.querySelector("#years-drop");
      
      //Crea un array para años
      let years = [];
      let d = new Date();
      let thisYear = d.getFullYear(); //Obtener este añ0
      let yearStart = thisYear - 10;  //Arranque en este año - 10
      
      //Agrega los valores al array
      for (let i = yearStart; i <= thisYear; i++) {
        years.push(i);
      }
      
      //Loop con el array de años
      for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
        //Crea el elemento option
        let item = document.createElement("option");
        //Crea el texto a agregar al elemento option
        let text = document.createTextNode(years[i]);
        //Agrega el valor del año al atributo value
        item.setAttribute("value", years[i]);
        //Agrega el texto al elemento option
        item.appendChild(text);
        //Agrega el elemento option a la lista select
        list.appendChild(item);
      }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Lista de Años</h1>

<select name="years" id="years-drop">
  <option>Selecciona</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitaras usar el objeto global [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) para obtener la fecha y mes actual.

Necesitaras usar los métodos [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) para obtener el año actual y [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) para obtener el mes actual.

y para asignar las opciones al select deberás usar el Node de [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), que es basicamente crear un elemento HTML y asignarlo como hijo.

```js
// Creacion del objeto date
const date = new Date();

// Se obtiene el elemento HTML
const selectedYear = document.getElementById('select-year');
const selectedMonth = document.getElementById('select-month');

// Obtienes el año actual
let year = date.getFullYear();

// Obtienes el mes actual
let month =  date.getMonth();

// Declaras la variable con la suma de años
let yearSum = 10;

// Ciclo for que comienza desde el año actual hasta 10 años mas.
// Se crea la opción y se asigna al select
for (let i = year; i <= year+yearSum; i++) {

  // Creación del elmento HTML option.
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  // Se asigna el valor de i al option.
  option.value = option.innerHTML = i;
  
  //Pregunta si i es igual al año actual
  if (i === year) option.selected = true;
  
  // Añade la option al final del select.
  selectedYear.appendChild(option);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  // Creación del elmento HTML option.
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  // Se asigna el valor de i al option.
  option.value = option.innerHTML = i;
  
  //Pregunta si i es igual al mes actual
  if (i === month) option.selected = true;
  
  // Añade la option al final del select.
  selectedMonth.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select name="years" id="select-year">
</select>

<select name="month" id="select-month">
</select>
```